# Finding at what state or OOM score value an app is killed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

App is getting killed with OOM Killer killing it on certain oom_score.
Is there any specific value set for OOM when to kill the process after reaching the value set or how it takes a decision when to kill?

If its done with some fixed value oom_score is there a way to change the value.

Can some one through in detail way how to handle the OOM to understand what exactly happening when OOM killer kill my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any specific value set for OOM when to kill the process after reaching the value set or how it takes a decision when to kill?

No. The OOM killer is only used when the system runs out of memory. When that happens, it starts by killing the process with the highest OOM score. The score is based on the amount of memory a process is using, with some adjustments based on various heuristics.

Generally speaking, if the OOM killer is being activated at all, either your system has too little memory, or a process is running out of control. This should never happen in an embedded device -- it's a sign of some sort of problem.

That all being said, you can adjust the OOM score for a process by writing a value into `/proc/$pid/oom_score_adj`. The value in that file is added to the process's OOM score, so a positive value will make the OOM killer more likely to target that process more often, and a negative value will make the OOM killer avoid the process.

Comment: Got it but my app is killed on once it got to OOM score of 780 or Mem usage reaches above 80%. Means that OOM will kill the process only after if my app uses above 80% of total memory. Is there a way I can configure that.

Comment: Yes — by adding more memory to your device. It's out of memory. *Something* has to go, and the process that's using 80% of memory is the obvious target.